# iterating over linkedBlockingQueue and removing elements at the same time

Tags: java

My code is as follows:

```java
private LinkedBlockingQueue<TrackedOperation> operations = new LinkedBlockingQueue<TrackedOperation>(10000);
        Iterator<TrackedOperation> it = operations.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            TrackedOperation op = operations.remove();
                            ...
        }
```

My question is:

Would iterator be always pointing to the head of the queue and is that the expected behavior?

If I am not making sense, then my question is what would be the behavior of iterator? Is my operations queue and iterator consistent in the above code?

Comment: What does the javadoc say?

Comment: You would generally `while(true) E e = queue.take();` with a blocking queue. Then interrupt the thread or send a special item to break the loop.

Comment: @assylias...the docs say for "take()" Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available. I dont understand what does waiting means here. What would be the behavior of while(queue.take()), if queue is empty.

Comment: it means your thread blocks until an item is available.

Answer (score 4):

Here what I do,

```
while (!linkedBlockingQueue.isEmpty()) {
    linkedBlockingQueue.remove(); //do what you want to with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only call it.remove() after you've called it.next(). The element returned by it.next() is the one that will then be removed by the it.remove() operation.

Comment: Not necessarily in a multi threaded environment which is the point of that queue.

Comment: do you have a reference for that claim? I can believe that the structure of the queue changes while iterating, but I have a very hard time believing that it.remove() will sometimes remove something other than 'the current item' retrieved by it.next() -- how would you even make an iterator do that?

Comment: Ah, I see - wow, even in the iterator interface spec, under the remove method, it says `The behavior of an iterator is unspecified if the underlying collection is modified while the iteration is in progress in any way other than by calling this method.` yikes.

Answer (score 0):

Accepting @assylias answer above

You would generally while(true) E e = queue.take(); with a blocking queue. Then interrupt the thread or send a special item to break the loop